# How can I get have Scrapy crawling inside a python project ?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a personal project which led me to use Selenium in order to get a public url address from a private [mail, password] couple.

I want to save info at this url and I followed the Scrapy tutorial to get how I could do it with this tool. But is there a way  to launch the crawling inside a Python project like `MyScrapClass.crawl()` instead of having the linux command `scrapy crawl MyScrapProject` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use CrawlerProcess or CrawlerRunner classes for running scrapy from within a python script..

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

example taken from the [scrapy website](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider)
# the script will block here until the crawling is finished
process.start()
```